# What causes loss of autofs CIFS share to hang Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: samba, automount, cifs, autofs

On 19.04, I use autofs to automount windows shares. It works great until I shut down the windows machine. Doing so hangs my 19.04 machine. My nemo-desktop becomes unusable, and I cannot restart gnome. I have to restart my 19.04 machine.

last kernel log entry says: kernel: CIFS VFS: Server has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...

Is there a way to shut down the windows machine, and have the CIFS shares 'released' so that I can keep using 19.04 without having to restart?

Comment: What value do you have for the timeout in your /etc/auto.master file? You could make it incredibly short like ... 5 or 10 seconds.

Comment: I have it at 30 seconds. It doesn't seem to unfreeze after that time. The log still references 120 seconds.